# Copy files from first level subfolder only to another location

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I want to copy all files in only second level subfolders to another location. All file names are unique. The second level subfolders in this example are 01102009, 05302009, and 09012010. Example:

```
C:\test\
  2009\
    01102009\
       file123.A09
       file567.B07
    05302009\
       fileabc.A09
       filexyz.A09
       ThirdLevelSubFolder\
          fileBLAH.B10
  2010\
     09012010\
        fileHello.A08
        fileBye.B10
  etc.
```

Should return:

```
C:\final\
   file123.A09
   file567.B07
   fileabc.A09
   filexyz.A09
   fileHello.A08
   fileBye.B10
```

Notice it did not copy fileBLAH.B10 which was in a third level subfolder.

If it helps, all files end in .A## or .B##, where ## is a two digit number.

I tried this:

```
robocopy "C:\test" "C:\final" s /LEV:2
```

but that copies over the second level folders (e.g., 01102009) and the files inside them. I just want the files.

I also tried:

```
for /r "C:\test" %i in (*.*) do copy "%~fi" "C:\final"
```

but that copies files in all subfolders, including third level ones, whereas I want only files in the second level subfolders.

Comment: Larry, you've used terms `first level` and `second level` in your question title and description, where this is actually a third level folder C:\test\2009\01102009\

Comment: There is a third level folder called `"ThirdLevelSubFolder"` under the second level folder `05302009`. But I guess if I consider "test" the 1st level folder, then I actually have four levels `(e.g., C:\test\2009\05302009\ThirdLevelSubFolder)`.

Answer (score 1):

**Final edit** according to **foxidrive**'s comment. You need two nested loops to treat files in the second level subfolder (although **aschipfl**'s solution with [`for /D` may be a bit more concise](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)):

```
for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir /B /A:D "C:\test\*.*"') do @for /F "delims=" %i in ('dir /B /A:D "C:\test\%~I\*.*"') do @echo copy /B "C:\test\%~I\%~i\*.*" "C:\final\*.*" 2>NUL
```

**Original answer**:

`for /r` = [Loop through files (Recurse subfolders)](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html); try (not recursing) `dir /B` in 
`FOR /F` = [Loop command: against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) instead as follows:.

```
for /F "delims=" %i in ('dir /B /A:D "C:\test\*.*"') do copy /B "C:\test\%~i\*.*" "C:\final\*.*" 2>NUL
```

Note that `2>NUL`  prevents displaying of the `The system cannot find the file specified` message if source folder is empty.

**Output** (with changed `C:\` to `D:\`): The first `dir /B` shows that we start with the target folder empty, while the last `dir /B` shows that the target was populated with copied files...

```
d:\bat>dir /B "d:\final\*.*"

d:\bat>for /F "delims=" %i in ('dir /B /A:D "d:\test\*.*"') do @copy /B /Y "d:\test\%~i\*.*" "d:\final\*.*" 2>NUL
d:\test\31441809\ttt.txt
        1 file(s) copied.
d:\test\ProcMon\LogfileAcrord32Start.CSV
d:\test\ProcMon\LogfileIE.CSV
d:\test\ProcMon\LogfileIEStart.CSV
d:\test\ProcMon\LogfileSwriter.CSV
d:\test\ProcMon\LogfileSwriterStart.CSV
        5 file(s) copied.
d:\test\ScreenCaptures\*.*
        0 file(s) copied.
d:\test\set\HKCU.txt
d:\test\set\hklm.txt
d:\test\set\regs.txt
d:\test\set\set.txt
d:\test\set\t!exclam!t.txt
        5 file(s) copied.

d:\bat>dir /B "d:\final\*.*"
HKCU.txt
hklm.txt
LogfileAcrord32Start.CSV
LogfileIE.CSV
LogfileIEStart.CSV
LogfileSwriter.CSV
LogfileSwriterStart.CSV
regs.txt
set.txt
t!exclam!t.txt
ttt.txt

d:\bat>
```

Comment: When I entered your command at the cmd prompt, all as one line, and hit enter, it generated six lines of output (one for each 1st level subfolder in C:\test (e.g., 2009, 2010 ... etc.) but for each line it said `0 file(s) copied`.

Comment: @Larry The code works fine here - did you have the right paths and files in the right places?

Comment: @Larry  I see your problem - you asked for 2nd level files but you really mean 3rd level files. `c:\test` is the first level.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is two nested `for /D` loops, each covering a certain directory hierarchy level:

```
@echo off
for /D %%A in ("C:\test\*") do (
  for /D %%B in ("%%~fA\*") do (
    xcopy /L /I "%%~fB\*.*" "C:\final"
  )
)
```

This code does actually not copy anything, it just lists what would be copied; to enable copying, remove the `/L` switch from `xcopy`.

The script does not filter against patterns `*.A??` and `*.B??`; if you want to do so, you will need two `xcopy` commands.
Further, it does not copy anything from the first directory level as your sample listing does not show any files there.

---

**Amendment:**
When I'm talking about directory levels, I consult the following definition:
All levels are numbered relatively to the root location `C:\test\`, so `2009\` is the 1st level, `01102009\` is the 2nd one, and so on.

Comment: This also worked. Took me some research to figure out how to implement it (I've used the cmd prompt maybe once in my life). I first tried entering everything as one line and got "%%A was unexpected at this time." Google search suggested it was meant to be run as a batch program. Had to look that up, too. So, for newbies out there, the way to run aschipfl's code: 1) copy his code into notepad, 2) save the file with a .bat extension (e.g.,"copyfiles.bat") anywhere you want, 3) double click the file and it will execute the code.

Comment: You can enter it as one line into command prompt (you may omit the `@echo off` part), but you need to replace all `%%` by `%` (this is also documented in the help text of the `for` command -- type `for /?` in command prompt...).